# Andrdoid studio emulator doesn't support google maps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Hi all I'm making an app that will use google maps api but my emulator keeps saying that google maps is not supported by my device even though my emulator is a google pixel which means it should support google maps.

I added my API key to the local.properties file
`

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
MAPS_API_KEY=API_KEY
```

`
And added the following code to the dependencies element in my project level build.gradle

```
uildscript{
    dependencies {
        classpath"com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the specified code in android docs is present in my module level build.gradle file under plugins

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.me.gcu.labstuff.androidcwk"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

and updated my android:value attribute as follows in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.me.gcu.labstuff.androidcwk">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Androidcwk">

        <!--
             TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

             To get one, follow the directions here:

                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

             Once you have your API key (it starts with "AIza"), define a new property in your
             project's local.properties file (e.g. MAPS_API_KEY=Aiza...), and replace the
             "YOUR_API_KEY" string in this file with "${MAPS_API_KEY}".
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and still my emulator says google maps is not supported. Any help would be extremely appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please don't share your API key on public websites like this one. Make sure to also restrict them.

Comment: Can you also provide the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: @jabamataro fixed it, thx for the edit